# Jquery plugin is not working and causing console errors, how do I fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I installed Shuffle.js from a codepen demo with some customizations to style and figure cards. I've added in recommended js code but the shuffle function doesn't seem work.

Getting several errors:

[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfj6e.png)

I've tried updating script based on some past answers to this problem. I've also downloaded and added the actual js file on my site and referenced it in the script. Here's what my script looks like right now:

```
<script src="/v/vspfiles/assets/js/shuffle.js"></script>
<script>
'use strict';

var Shuffle = window.shuffle;

var Demo = function (element) {
  this.element = element;

  // Log out events.
  this.addShuffleEventListeners();

  this.shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
    itemSelector: '.picture-item',
    sizer: element.querySelector('.my-sizer-element'),
  });

  this._activeFilters = [];

  this.addFilterButtons();
  this.addSorting();
  this.addSearchFilter();

  this.mode = 'exclusive';
};

Demo.prototype.toArray = function (arrayLike) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike);
};

Demo.prototype.toggleMode = function () {
  if (this.mode === 'additive') {
    this.mode = 'exclusive';
  } else {
    this.mode = 'additive';
  }
};

/**
 * Shuffle uses the CustomEvent constructor to dispatch events. You can listen
 * for them like you normally would (with jQuery for example). The extra event
 * data is in the `detail` property.
 */
Demo.prototype.addShuffleEventListeners = function () {
  var handler = function (event) {
    console.log('type: %s', event.type, 'detail:', event.detail);
  };

  this.element.addEventListener(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, handler, false);
  this.element.addEventListener(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, handler, false);
};

Demo.prototype.addFilterButtons = function () {
  var options = document.querySelector('.filter-options');

  if (!options) {
    return;
  }

  var filterButtons = this.toArray(
    options.children
  );

  filterButtons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', this._handleFilterClick.bind(this), false);
  }, this);
};

Demo.prototype._handleFilterClick = function (evt) {
  var btn = evt.currentTarget;
  var isActive = btn.classList.contains('active');
  var btnGroup = btn.getAttribute('data-group');

  // You don't need _both_ of these modes. This is only for the demo.

  // For this custom 'additive' mode in the demo, clicking on filter buttons
  // doesn't remove any other filters.
  if (this.mode === 'additive') {
    // If this button is already active, remove it from the list of filters.
    if (isActive) {
      this._activeFilters.splice(this._activeFilters.indexOf(btnGroup));
    } else {
      this._activeFilters.push(btnGroup);
    }

    btn.classList.toggle('active');

    // Filter elements
    this.shuffle.filter(this._activeFilters);

  // 'exclusive' mode lets only one filter button be active at a time.
  } else {
    this._removeActiveClassFromChildren(btn.parentNode);

    var filterGroup;
    if (isActive) {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
      filterGroup = Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS;
    } else {
      btn.classList.add('active');
      filterGroup = btnGroup;
    }

    this.shuffle.filter(filterGroup);
  }
};

Demo.prototype._removeActiveClassFromChildren = function (parent) {
  var children = parent.children;
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    children[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
};

Demo.prototype.addSorting = function () {
  var menu = document.querySelector('.sort-options');

  if (!menu) {
    return;
  }

  menu.addEventListener('change', this._handleSortChange.bind(this));
};

Demo.prototype._handleSortChange = function (evt) {
  var value = evt.target.value;
  var options = {};

  function sortByDate(element) {
    return element.getAttribute('data-created');
  }

  function sortByTitle(element) {
    return element.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase();
  }

  if (value === 'date-created') {
    options = {
      reverse: true,
      by: sortByDate,
    };
  } else if (value === 'title') {
    options = {
      by: sortByTitle,
    };
  }

  this.shuffle.sort(options);
};

// Advanced filtering
Demo.prototype.addSearchFilter = function () {
  var searchInput = document.querySelector('.js-shuffle-search');

  if (!searchInput) {
    return;
  }

  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', this._handleSearchKeyup.bind(this));
};

/**
 * Filter the shuffle instance by items with a title that matches the search input.
 * @param {Event} evt Event object.
 */
Demo.prototype._handleSearchKeyup = function (evt) {
  var searchText = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();

  this.shuffle.filter(function (element, shuffle) {

    // If there is a current filter applied, ignore elements that don't match it.
    if (shuffle.group !== Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS) {
      // Get the item's groups.
      var groups = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-groups'));
      var isElementInCurrentGroup = groups.indexOf(shuffle.group) !== -1;

      // Only search elements in the current group
      if (!isElementInCurrentGroup) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    var titleElement = element.querySelector('.picture-item__title');
    var titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();

    return titleText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  window.demo = new Demo(document.getElementById('grid'));
});
</script>
```

Any insight into what I need to remedy to get this working properly would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the path to some of your fonts is wrong. CSS issue, not JS.

Comment: The /v/vspfiles/assets/js/shuffle.js script is not loading. Look at your console "illegal return statement". This most likely means that there is some JS code in your script causing an error. Look for a return; from a non-function in that JS file.